# How to reinstall PIL on mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I have been for hours on this. I needed to get jpeglib and PIL reinstalled.

I installed jpeg lib from http://www.ijg.org/, please tell me if that's right.

I still have to reinstall PIL. I installed Fink, for apt-get, but still am not clear how to uninstall completely PIL before installing it.

And then installation, do i do `apt-get install py-pil` only? I see different instructions [here](http://colbypalmer.com/index.php?/colbyworld/blogEntry/install_libjpeg_and_pil_on_os_x_leopard/) and [here](http://colbypalmer.com/index.php?/colbyworld/blogEntry/install_libjpeg_and_pil_on_os_x_leopard/). Which way should I go? I also can't figure out, does `sudo python setup.py install` reinstall python 2.6, or it just installs whichever thing i am in the directory of? However:

> [petarpetrov@/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PIL]$ sudo python setup.py install
>   python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

thanks in advance

Comment: well, that was a pain on it's own, but yes, I installed Fink from http://www.finkproject.org/ and it seems to have apt-get in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't muck about with fink. That uses a completely separate install of Python and all its dependencies. It really won't help with your actual problem.

Secondly, you're trying to run things from inside site-packages - this is wrong. Go back to the directory where you *downloaded* PIL (or download it again, if you don't still have it) and run `sudo python setup.py install`.

And no, it won't reinstall Python - it *uses* python to run the setup of the directory you're in.

Comment: Ah, thanx, and how do I remove the old PIL? i got a folder: 
 
`/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PIL` and 
`/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PIL.pth` and
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/py2app/recipes/PIL` with bunch of things there

do i remove all of that bofore installing PIL anew?

Comment: And another question. I have python 2.3, 2.5, 2.6. My site uses apparently 2.6 (no idea how to control that). How do I know that PIL will install for 2.6 rather than 2.3 or 2.5?

Comment: assuming `python -V` shows 2.6, then running `python setup.py install` will use that python and install it for 2.6. Shouldn't need to delete anything first.